# function error gettinf in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas

Transcript.groupby(['event','offer_type'])['offer_type'].count()

C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\grouper.py in get_grouper(obj, key, axis, level, sort, observed, mutated, validate, dropna)
858                 in_axis, level, gpr = False, gpr, None
859             else:
--> 860                 raise KeyError(gpr)
861         elif isinstance(gpr, Grouper) and gpr.key is not None:
862             # Add key to exclusions

KeyError: 'offer_type

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i am getting error to use groupby function in jupyter notebook in python